# Does Collection's contain method ever return false for an instance added to it?

Tags: java, collections

I was going through Joshua Bloch's online Chapter on "overridding equals() method".
Here's the [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110622072109/http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf).
The following section confuses me,

> Reflexivity—The first requirement says merely that an object must be
>   equal to itself. It is hard to imagine violating this requirement
>   unintentionally. If you were to violate it and then add an instance of
>   your class to a collection, the collection’s contains method would
>   almost certainly say that the collection did not contain the instance
>   that you just added.

Question - Is it possible for a collection's contain method to return false on an instance added to it?

I tried but the result returned is always true.

Comment: "overridding equals() method" Perhaps the method is overridden to `return false;`

Comment: @KarthikT overriding equals means I'm forcing to violate the contract. My doubt was regarding the statement saying that contains method will definitely return false. I'm looking for a scenario in which this statement holds true.

Comment: Perhaps your equals method mistakenly converts the Strings from one side of the comparison to uppercase, but leaves the others in original case.  Or perhaps you convert Dates to GMT inconsistently, etc...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it specifically says "if you violate" then it can return false

Comment: @KarthikT it doesn't say "if you violate", it says if you wanted to violate then there's a way to do so, which someone might unintentionally come across. User fge has explained below how to avoid such a mistake. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the point, have this simple class:

```
class C {
    private int i;
    public C(int i) { this.i = i; }
}
```

Now, if you do:

```
C c1 = new C(1);
C c2 = new C(1);

List<C> l = new ArrayList<C>();

l.add(c1);
```

`l.contains(c2)` will return `false`, since `c2.equals(c1)` is `false`, in spite of the fact that both instances have the same constructor arguments.

This is because class `C` does not override `.equals()` nor `.hashCode()`.

In general, each time your class is bound to be used in a `Collection` of any kind, you had better override both of these methods. In this case:

```
// Note: final class, final member -- that makes this class immutable
final class C {
    private final int i;
    public C(int i) { this.i = i; }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return i; }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        // no object equals null
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        // an object is always equal to itself
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        // immutable class: if the class of the other is not the same,
        // objects are not equal
        if (getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        // Both objects are of the same class: check their members
        return i == ((C) o).i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in this case l.contains(c2) should be false.

Comment: Well, isn't this what I have written? Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

> Question - Is it possible for a collection's contain method to return false on an instance added to it?

Not unless the added object's `equals()` violates the contract, as the quote from the book explains.

As suggested by @Karthik T, try this with an object whose `equals()` unconditionally returns `false` (thereby violating the contract).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration of a collection's contains method returning false for an object that has just been added to the collection. I took a normal equals and hashCode, generated by Eclipse, and changed the equals method to be non-reflexive. Specifically, it returns false when comparing an object to itself.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  int someValue;
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + someValue;
    return result;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      // Bad. Non-reflexive. Should return true.
      return false;
    }
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Test other = (Test) obj;
    if (someValue != other.someValue)
      return false;
    return true;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Test> myList = new LinkedList<Test>();
    Test myObject = new Test();
    myList.add(myObject);
    System.out.println(myList.contains(myObject));
  }
}
```